# How can I make Dispatch work in react native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, expo

App Context.tsx

---

```
import React, {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useReducer,
  useEffect,
  ReactNode,
  Dispatch,
} from "react";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { StateType, ActionType } from "../types/contextTypes";

const storeData = async (name: string, value: string) => {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem(name, value);
};

const returnStoredData = async (name: string) => {
  var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(name);
  if (value) {
    return value;
  } else return null;
};
// Initial state
const initialState = {
  user: null,
  access: null,
};

// Reducer function
const appReducer = (state: StateType, action: ActionType) => {

  //I want to reach here with dispatch
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_USER": {
      return { ...state, user: action.payload };
    }
    case "SET_ACCESS":
      if (action.payload) {
        storeData("ACCESS", action.payload);
        return { ...state, access: action.payload };
      }

    case "LOGOUT": {
      AsyncStorage.removeItem("ACCESS");

      return { ...state, access: null, refresh: null };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

// Create the context
export const AppContext = createContext<{
  state: StateType;
  dispatch: Dispatch<ActionType>;
}>({ state: initialState, dispatch: () => null });

export const useAppContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext);
};

export const AppProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(appReducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadStoredData = async () => {
      const storedAccess = await returnStoredData("ACCESS");

      dispatch({ type: "SET_ACCESS", payload: storedAccess });
    };

    loadStoredData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

RegisterScreen.tsx

---

```
`import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  Button,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";
import { Formik } from "formik";

import AppText from "../components/AppText";
import * as AppleAuthentication from "expo-apple-authentication";
import { loginApple } from "../api/postRequest";
import Colors from "../config/Colors";
import { AppContext } from "../context/AppContext";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { router } from "expo-router";

function RegisterScreen() {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext);

  async function sendRegister(values: any) {
    console.log(values);
  }

  async function appleLogin() {
    try {
      const credential = await AppleAuthentication.signInAsync({
        requestedScopes: [
          AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.FULL_NAME,
          AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.EMAIL,
        ],
      });
      loginApple(credential)
        .then((response: any) => {
          console.log(response.data.access_token);
          dispatch({ type: "SET_ACCESS", payload: response.data.access_token });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error in loginApple: ", error);
        });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <AppText>Register</AppText>

      <AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButton
        buttonType={AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButtonType.SIGN_IN}
        buttonStyle={AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButtonStyle.BLACK}
        cornerRadius={5}
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={appleLogin}
      />
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ username: "", password: "" }}
        onSubmit={(values) => sendRegister(values)}
      >
        {({ handleChange, handleSubmit }) => (
          <>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.text}
              placeholder={"UserName"}
              autoCorrect={false}
              onChangeText={handleChange("username")}
            />

            <TextInput
              style={styles.text}
              placeholder={"Password"}
              secureTextEntry
              textContentType="password"
              onChangeText={handleChange("password")}
            />
            <Button title="Register" onPress={() => handleSubmit} />
          </>
        )}
      </Formik>
      <Button title="Login" onPress={() => console.log("Go To Home Screen")} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  cont: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: "100%",
  },
  icon: {
    borderRadius: 40,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  text: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.secondary,
    color: "white",
    width: "80%",
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 40,
    marginVertical: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  button: {
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
  },
});

export default RegisterScreen;
`
```

_layout.tsx

---

```
import { Slot } from "expo-router";
import { AppContext } from "../context/AppContext";
import { useContext } from "react";

export default function Root() {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      <Slot />
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

(app)/_layout.tsx

---

```
import { Stack } from "expo-router/stack";
import Colors from "../../config/Colors";
import { View, Button, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome";
import {
  faBackspace,
  faBackward,
  faCaretLeft,
  faChevronLeft,
  faLeftLong,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { Redirect, router } from "expo-router";
import { AppContext } from "../../context/AppContext";
import { useContext } from "react";

export default function AppLayout() {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext);

  if (!state.access) {
    return <Redirect href="RegisterScreen" />;
  }

  return (
    <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="PostScreen"
        options={{
          animation: "slide_from_bottom",
          title: "Create A Post",
          headerBackground: () => (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: Colors.background }} />
          ),
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                router.back();
              }}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronLeft} size={20} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="CardDetailScreen"
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          animation: "fade_from_bottom",
        }}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

├── app
│   ├── (app)
│   │   ├──(tabs)
│   │   ├── _layout.tsx
│   │
│   │
│   ├── _layout.tsx
│   ├── RegisterScreen.tsx

Dispatch does not work. I am able to access state but when I choose to dispatch and set_access it does not work. I never enter app reducer function. I am using expo-router as well and was following this [Link](https://docs.expo.dev/router/reference/authentication/#example-authentication-context)

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to recommend redux-saga to somebody who's not even using redux when the maintainer of redux itself is heavily discouraging its use, @AqeelAhmad . https://stackoverflow.com/a/72370662/2188587

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the dispatch got called

```js
    const loadStoredData = async () => {
      const storedAccess = await returnStoredData("ACCESS");
      // Has the following line be executed ?
      dispatch({ type: "SET_ACCESS", payload: storedAccess });
    };
```

Comment: No it is not being called. I am using expo-router and have wrapped the app context on _layout.tsx is this the highest possible level

Comment: I figured it out it my context was being passed in correct instead I had to use <AppProvider>
But know my _layout.tsx is not rerendering when state is changed.

Comment: Wien you use expo Router why you don’t use link (https://docs.expo.dev/router/navigating-pages/)?